# why does string.search fail in this instance?

Tags: javascript

I'm pasting the exact strings that javascript prints:

```
string: "testare atasament fisier,tip nota - reamintire (1),Diverse,Telefon,Fisier,tip nota Azom" without the ""

substring: "tip nota - reamintire (1)" again without the ""
```

just writing those "" to show that there are no empty spaces anywhere funny (also checked in the code)

The result of

```
string.search(substring);
```

is always -1, how come? which character is messing up the search?

note that i don't use the names string and substring for the variables in my actual code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It worked for me - using `indexOf`

```
"testare atasament fisier,tip nota - reamintire (1),Diverse,Telefon,Fisier,tip nota Azom"
.indexOf("tip nota - reamintire (1)");
```

yields

```
25
```

**search** takes a regular expression where **indexOf** takes a string.

The parenthesis inside of "tip nota - reamintire (1)" act as a group, you would have to escape them for it to match an actual parenthesis.

Comment: well, i guess it's too late in the day for me to think of the simple solutions. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

The `search` method takes a regular expression object, and if you give it a string, it's used to create a regular expression object.

Reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/search

The `(` and `)` have a special meaning in a regular expression, so they are not included in the characters that should be matched. You will actually be looking for the string `"tip nota - reamintire 1"`.

You can use the `\` character to escape the characters in the regular expression. If you use them in a string literal, you have to escape the `\` characters, so:

```
var substring = "tip nota - reamintire \\(1\\)";
```

You can also use a regular expression literal:

```
var substring = /tip nota - reamintire \(1\)/;
```

Answer (score 2):

This is because [search function](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_search.asp) has a regexp as parameter.
You have to escape the parentheses with `\\`:

```
var string= "testare atasament fisier,tip nota - reamintire (1),Diverse,Telefon,Fisier,tip nota Azom" ;
var substring = "tip nota - reamintire (1)" ;
var substring2 = "tip nota - reamintire \\(1\\)" ;

alert(string.search(substring)); // -1 
alert(string.search(substring2)); // 25
```